# If $f \in L^{\infty}(\Bbb R^d) \cap C_u(\Omega)$, then $\rho_{\epsilon} * f \to f$ uniformly over $\Omega$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence

Consider the following statement:

> If $(\rho_{\epsilon})_{\epsilon > 0}$ is an approximation identity and $f \in L^{\infty}(\Bbb R^d) \cap C_u(\Omega)$, then $\rho_{\epsilon} * f \to f$ uniformly over $\Omega$. Where $\Omega$ is possibly any $\neq \varnothing$ subset of $\Bbb R^d$.

I know that if $f \in L^{\infty}(\Bbb R^d) \cap C(\Bbb R^d)$, then $\rho_{\epsilon} * f \to f$ over any compact in $\Bbb R^d$. The proof uses the fact that if $K$ is a compact, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K + \overline{B(0,1)}$, etc. Obviously, one can't proceed in the same way to prove the above statement.

Frankly, I am not sure whether or not the statement is true, but it is written in my notebook, so there is a good chance that the professor said it.

Is the statement true? If so, any clues on how to prove it?

Comment: What is $C_u (\Omega)$?

Comment: @PhoemueX it denotes the set of uniformly continuous functions over $\Omega$.